# ESPTool 3-run stub fail error

Tags: esp8266, error

I'm trying to program my NodeMCU ESP8266 ESP-12E module with AT commands. However, whenever I try and flash to my ESP8266 using ESPTool, I get a 3-run stub fail error. Can anyone tell me why I get this error and how to fix it?
I have my suspicions that it might be the fact that I haven't pulled any of the pins, but I've been told that GPIO0, GPIO2, GPIO15, and CH_PD are all already pulled to the proper positions by default. If that may be the reason behind this error, could someone explain to me how exactly I should pull the pins, whether it be with a circuit or through code?
If it helps, I'm trying to follow along with [this resource.](https://www.instructables.com/id/Program-Any-ESP8266-Boardmodule-With-AT-Commands-F/)
The only thing the ESP is connected to is the computer with USB.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to update and let anyone who had a similar issue learn how I solved the problem.
My baud rate was set to 1152000 rather than 115200. Setting it to 115200 solved my problem.